# How to disable menu and swipe back gesture on ionic 5?

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic5

I want to disable both swiping back and left hand side menu display on my login page, I can't find any information that works.

I have tried (in both ionViewWillEnter and ngOnInit)

```
this.routerOutlet.swipeGesture = false
```

I also tried

```
this.menu.enable(false)
```

This deactivates the menu button on the header bar but does not deactivate the menu when swiping.

Comment: share your menu code and login code. A @Stackblitz MVP will be more help full

Comment: this.menu.swipeEnable(false); or set swipeGesture= false in html page as property

Comment: Thanks @RaviAshara this works, I don't where the code I used came from orginally..